# Alternatives to encodeURI and encodeURIComponent to replace escape

Tags: javascript, node.js, encodeuricomponent

I am posting data to a site that often includes French characters. This site has a form which handles the French characters fine but I had trouble when sending doing this inside a node program.

An example would be a field with the name: "Maevà". When I look at the dev tools in chrome I can see that the request encodes this name as: `Maev%E0`.

This works fine and in my code if I use `escape(Maevà)` it returns `Maev%E0` which works perfectly.

Unfortunately escape is deprecated so I tried to use encodeURIComponent and encodeURI but they both return `Maev%C3%A0` which does not work.

Is there something else I can use?

Comment: `Maev%C3%A0` is the correct encoding. You can see it correctly populating the input when used in a Google Search URL - https://www.google.com/search?q=-----Maev%C3%A0----- (it sounds like you have a problem with whatever code you have to *decode* that data and you should be looking to fix that instead of trying to reproduce the behaviour of `escape`)

Comment: Chrome seems to encode it the same way though so surely it's just an alternative encoding that I should be able to replicate without `escape`?

Comment: "*This site has a form which handles the French characters fine*" - please show us that form, and ideally post the server code that handles the request.